# Continuity of a linear function from $l^1$ to $l^1$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $(a_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of terms in $\mathbb{R}$ satisfying that for each $(x_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \in l^1$, the sequence $(a_kx_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges absolutely. Consider the function $T: l^1 \to l^1$ defined by $T((x_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}})=(a_kx_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$. Then $T$ is linear and continuous.

I know $T$ is linear, but what is a reasonable strategy to show this is continuous?

Comment: $|a_k| < C$ because otherwise, you could find $(x_k) \in l^1$ such that $\sum_k |x_k a_k| = \infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A linear operator is continuous if and only if it is bounded.  By one of the comments above, it is possible to show that the sequence $a_k$ must be bounded (for otherwise, $Tx$ for $x\in\ell^1$ would not itself be an element of $\ell^1$).  Therefore, $|a_k|\leq C$ for some $C\geq 0$.

Next, recall that a linear operator $T:\ell^1\rightarrow\ell^1$ is bounded if and only if there exists $K\geq 0$ such that $|Tx|_{\ell^1}\leq K|x|_{\ell^1}$.

What is $K$?